# How to fix long delays and "Callback timed out" errors with NIS master and slave set up?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, nis

I have an NIS master and slave set up, and whenever I do something that requires synchronization between the two (such as adding a new user), there are long delays that eventually end in a "Callback timed out" message.  How do I fix that?  This is with two Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) systems.

Answer (score 1):

on the MASTER nis /etc/ypserv.securenets along with your network definitions put a line similar to :

```
host  10.10.10.10
```

where `10.10.10.10` is the IP address of your SLAVE server.

On the SLAVE server (same file) put

```
host  11.11.11.11
```

where `11.11.11.11` is the IP of the MASTER server. And that's it :)